# Can I pass two conditionals to build a key/value pair in the same dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have two if-statements that need to be run in order to get all the information I need to build a dictionary.  I have a text file 'file.txt' which has values separated by lines. A basic representation of my code would look like:

```
dict = {}
    for line in 'file.txt':
        line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith('Key: '):
                key = print(line)
```

and at this point I need the other if-statement to get me the value which needs to be paired with 'key' that I just defined:

```
elif line.startswith('Value: '):
    value = print(line)
```

Now I need to update the dictionary, but I'm out of scope and I don't know how to tie `key` and `value` together in the same dictionary, whose values were obtained by going line-by-line through `'file.txt'` to ensure the keys are paired with the correct values.  Is there a way to do this?

The file (when open) looks like a list separated by newlines: `"Filename: name, Size: 200MB, Version: 2.2.2, etc..."` This pattern repeats.  So I need to grab 'Filename', skip 'Size', grab 'Version', and put the two together as a key/value pair.

Comment: Can you show a sample of what your file looks like?

Comment: @idjaw updated as per your request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the key.  Keep looking until you find a value.  If your data file is a simple alternation, the "None" stuff in this code won't matter.  If you have intermittent errors in this respect, you can harness the "None"

```
dict = {}
infile = open("in", 'r')
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split(',')
    print "line:  ", line
    for field in line:
        field = field.strip()
        print "field:", field
        if field.startswith('Filename: '):
            key = field.split(':')[1]
            value = None

        elif field.startswith('Version: '):
            value = field.split(':')[1]
            if key is not None:
                dict[key] = value
                value = None
                key = None

print dict
```

Here is the output, given your input line:

```
line:   ['Filename: name', ' Size: 200MB', ' Version: 2.2.2']
field: Filename: name
field: Size: 200MB
field: Version: 2.2.2
{' name': ' 2.2.2'}
```

Comment: doesn't adding `value = None` at the end of the first if-statement make `value` always `None` whenever it sees `"Filename: "`?  That effectively just resets what your second elif statement does, doesn't it?

Comment: value is None except for the short period in the second if when it has just been defined and stored.  Note that I never check it; if you get a case where the value precedes the key, you can add code to the first if to store the pair, as well.  Alternately, you can put the check (are both not None?) at the bottom of the outer for loop, after the entire line has been examined.  I can't help with the logic here, as I don't know the variety of input you might get.

Comment: Glad to be of help; that's why SO is here.  There are more Pythonic ways to handle this (your format is close to JSON parsing or direct conversion to a dictionary for each line), but I kept it to a level I hope you can refine as desired.

Comment: I know it's messy - hopefully i'll learn enough Python soon to be able to truncate it a bit